# Make ajax request to Control Method in Web Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have control

> LogInOut.ascx

which i use on different pages `*.aspx`

I need to add logic on button click.

I need to make ajax call to contol's method but i don't know how to get access to it.

What i try : `LogInOut.ascx/validateUser, /validateUser, /Controls/LogInOut.ascx/validateUser,` but always get error in ajax call

*( in debug mode i never was in this method, so problem in javascript).

Comment: Mark the Method which you are trying to use through ajax as "WebMethod". Also for this to work, you will have to enable the PageMethods in the Update Panel / Script Manger. Note: THe WebMethod should always be a static.

Comment: @Sreenath, yes, i did it .   [WebMethod]
  public static string ValidateUser(string userName, string userPassword)

Comment: i missed to mention. The method should be in aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a page method declared within an ASCX user control,  use an ASMX web service.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1423555.aspx